# Power BI: making a new column in "Transform" based on two columns

Tags: powerbi, pivot

I am trying to pivot this table to have the dates for each "ticket_id" in one row. I am trying to create a new condition based on my business use case that
`if((state_id) == 1 AND ('owner') == 1 then 1 else 0`  and pivoting the table based on it. but I can't make the column based on TWO condition in the `conditional column` option in **Edit query** window.

Any ideas please to pivot this table, or create the if statement with the two conditions?

Note: I could pivot the table perfectly if based on **state_id** only. but the issue is when having two columns to pivot based on.

[image: table to pivot]

Comment: You wants the new column state_id first?

Comment: I want the new column    ('state_new') = (if((state_id) == 1 AND ('owner') == 1) then 1 ELSE 0 ..... then deleting 'state_id', and 'owner' and pivot based on 'state_new' @mkRabbani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Power Query Editor** you can use this below code for generating the new Custom column based on other two columns - state_id and owern. After that you can use the new column for your pivoting purpose-

```
if [state_id] = 1 and [owner] = 1 then 1 else 0
```

Here is sample output-

[image]